# How do I access a windows control (checkbox) that is created dynamically in a WPF treeview?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, navigation, treeview, controls

I have a WPF Tree View with hierarchical data templates that loads objects and displays them fine. Within the children of the treeview, I am showing the "Name" of the object in the Tree View using a TextBlock, along with a Check Box next to it. Here is my code for reference:

```
<DockPanel Name="test1" Margin="10,10,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.Column="0">
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <local:CheckBoxCommand x:Key="cbc"></local:CheckBoxCommand>
            <src:TreeViewFilter x:Key="MyList" />

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:TreeViewParent}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderAttributes}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameAndCount}" FontSize="24"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:OrderAttribute}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderAttributes}">
                <StackPanel Name="test" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <CheckBox Command="{StaticResource cbc}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=NameAndParent}" Visibility="{Binding Path=CheckBoxVisible}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameAndCount}" FontSize="16"/>
                    </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </DockPanel.Resources>
        <TreeView Name="treeView1" BorderThickness="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TreeViewItem.Selected="filterByBatchStatus"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

When A user checks a checkbox in the tree, certain stuff happens in my application based on which checkbox is checked. The way I know which checkbox is being checked is by passing a paramater through a command, and that parameter is bound to the "NameAndParent" of the object. All of this works fine.

My problem begins when I give the user the option to save which checkboxes have been checked and I save the "Name" of each object next to the checked box into an XML. As you can see, I am only saving the "Name" of the object, but this name has no hook to the checkbox, So I can't go back and "find" the associated checkbox.

When I give the user the option to load one of these saved files, I want to traverse the tree and check the boxes that were saved. The problem is that the checkboxes DONT HAVE A NAME, OR UID, and I cant assign them one through binding because that is not allowed.

Is there anyway to traverse the tree view and somehow compare the saved name to the name of each element child in the tree, and then check that specific checkbox, Or is this something that has to be programmed in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a boolean IsChecked property in the class that contains your Data, and bind the CheckBox.IsChecked to that. instead of having to manipulate the view, you can more easily manipulate the data it is bound to, removing the need for fancy Visual-Tree operations, and removing the dependency between your application logic and your UI. This is the most important realization of the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern.

If you do not want to introduce UI-related logic (such as the IsChecked property I mentioned) into your Data Model, you will have to introduce a ViewModel in between the Model and the View.

Comment: Another question..so this works when the hierarchical tree is not expanded. So if I load the data, change the specific bools to true, and then expand the tree, everything works fine and the checkboxes are checked. If the tree is expanded and i can visually see them, the boxes are not checked. Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: Or even more specific, How do I use a dependency and fire property changed with a checkbox? I have used it with a string in my UI and got it to work, but what about with a checkbox?

Comment: I don't think DependencyProperties belong into ViewModels. You should leverage INotifyPropertyChandged. See http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html

Comment: The problem with DependencyProperties in ViewModels (or just plain data) is that you must derive your objects from DependencyObject, and they acquire thread affinity, which is not a good thing for data nor ViewModels.

Comment: I used INotifyPropertyChanged just like I have before and it sort of works, heres the problem: If I dont expand the tree (so i can see the boxes) And I load some bools, and then load some different ones, and keep doing that and then expand, the boxes are checked appropriately. As soon as I expand and visually see the boxes, loading from there on out does not update the boxes visually whether they are expanded in view or not. Any idea why expanding and visually seeing the boxes ends any visual updating?

Comment: Can you post the code of your Model / ViewModel? and the updated XAML including the IsChecked binding?

Comment: I just asked a new question with all the code for possible more advice, here is the link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164045/how-to-visually-update-checkboxes-in-ui-that-are-bounded-to-boolean-ischecked-va