# How to visually update checkboxes in UI that are bounded to boolean isChecked variable in WPF c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, checkbox, inotifypropertychanged

So I have a TreeView that has heirarchical data templates that have CheckBoxes in the lowest layer. These CheckBoxes are bound to a "isChecked" boolean value in the ViewModel. What I have been attempting to do is load the various variables indicating to me which checkboxes to check, change the boolean isChecked in the model to true, therefore resulting in the specific CheckBoxes in the TreeView being update visually. Here is my code for reference:

XAML: (of TreeView I am working with)

```
<DockPanel Name="test1" Margin="10,10,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.Column="0">
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <local:CheckBoxCommand x:Key="cbc"></local:CheckBoxCommand>
            <src:TreeViewFilter x:Key="MyList" />

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:TreeViewParent}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderAttributes}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameAndCount}" FontSize="24"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:OrderAttribute}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderAttributes}">
                <StackPanel Name="test" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <CheckBox Command="{StaticResource cbc}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=NameAndParent}" Visibility="{Binding Path=CheckBoxVisible}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </CheckBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameAndCount}" FontSize="16"/>
                    </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </DockPanel.Resources>
        <TreeView Name="treeView1" BorderThickness="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TreeViewItem.Selected="filterByBatchStatus"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

C# code in ViewModel (pertaining to the problem):

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged2;

protected void FirePropertyChanged2(string CheckBoxChecked)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged2 != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged2(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(CheckBoxChecked));
        }
    }

public static bool cbc;

public bool CheckBoxChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CheckBoxCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckBoxCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckBoxCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CheckBoxChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(OrderAttribute), new UIPropertyMetadata((bool)false));

bool _isChecked;
    public bool isChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }

        set
        {
            if (_isChecked != value)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                FirePropertyChanged2("CheckBoxChecked");
            }
        }
    }
```

If I load the values, update the booleans, and then expand the tree (So I can visually see them), the correct checkboxes are checked and everything works fine. The Problem comes into play when I load different checkboxes after initially visually seeing the first loaded checkboxes, change the booleans, then the Checkboxes do not change according, (dont change at all).

The part that stumps me is that if i do multiple loads, change the booleans over and over, WITHOUT expanding the tree and VISUALLY SEEING the boxes, and then expand the tree, the correct boxes are checked. As soon as I can visually expand and see the checkboxes, any post loading does not update the checkboxes, regardless if whether or not I expand or unexpand the tree.

Comment: it looks like you're only doing the "FirePropertyChanged2" on "CheckBoxChecked" and not "isChecked", which you bound to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow... you have some serious issues here. First of all, as I said in your previous question, [DependencyProperties don't belong into ViewModels](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html). Second, your CheckBox is located inside a HierarchicalDataTemplate defined for the Type src:OrderAttribute, and therefore all bindings there are going to search for properties of that type. Third, it is not clear to me what string parameter you are invoking the PropertyChanged event with, but it should be the name of a CLR property in your class, to which the UI is bound. I strongly suggest you take a look at [This WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Home.html)  to at least understand the basics of MVVM, INotifyPropertyChanged and DataTemplating, before trying to do complex hierarchical presentation layers.

Edit: Remove the DependencyProperty from the OrderAttribute Class, and use a regular bool property, then when calling PropertyChanged, do so by passing a string parameter containing the name of that property:

```
public bool MyBool 
{ 
   get { return _mybool; }
   set {
         _mybool = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("MyBool");
       }
}

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
}
```

Comment: For your 2nd point, The boolean value is in the OrderAttribute class. If you look at the textblock next to the checkbox, I tried to mimick the same type of binding because it worked for the textblock binding to data in the OrderAttribute (that is my model, maybe im confusing model/viewmodel). For the 3rd point, you are right, it is not a string. I tried to use the bool  but the PropertyChanged() event handler only excepts a string parameter. As for the 1st point, I dont know, I used that for the TextBlock in the tree and it worked fine and updated the UI immediately

Comment: You're going to run into serious problems if you define DependencyProperties in non-visual elements of your applications (such as Models or ViewModels). DependencyObjects have thread affinity, which means you cannot modify any of their properties from a different thread than the thread in which they were created, which again would have to be the UI Thread if you intend to bind them to the UI.

Comment: I tried your edit, no dependency properties, still same error. What is the propertyName in my example? Just dont understand why when I change the isChecked from false to true, and then expand tree it works. but then any subsequent changes dont visually update, tree expanded or not

Comment: Have you read the tutorial I linked to? the elements are ok when you expand the tree after setting the data because the UIElements are being created and bound to the correct data, whereas when you change the data and not NotifyPropertyChange correctly it doesn't get refreshed in the UI.

Comment: Youre right, the dependency properties I thought I was using aren't even being used. I fiddled around and got it to work, thanks for the help

Comment: got really scared with the "Wow... you have some serious issues here."  comment